# OOXML update Content Controls in .docx document headers

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am opening a .docx file, using the following code to go through all content controls and setting there text to "the foo bar text".  This works great for content controls that are in the document body.
The issue is it never updates the content controls that are in the header and footer.
Is there something I am missing?

```
        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(resultDocumentPath, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
            foreach (SdtElement sdt in mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>())
            {
                Run formattedRun = new Run();
                RunProperties runProperties = new RunProperties();
                runProperties.Append(new Text("the foo bar text"));
                formattedRun.Append(runProperties);
                sdt.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(formattedRun)));

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers and footers are stored in separate parts from the main document body.

In the raw OpenXML markup, the respective files are "header#.xml" and "footer#.xml".

In the OpenXML SDK, you will need to loop through the `MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts` and `MainDocumentPart.FooterParts`.

Comment: Cheers that worked, took a little tinkering, but the put me down the correct path